# How to pass a connection to a method in vba?

Tags: vba

I  am trying to pass `adodb.connection` object to a method, but get a compile error

```
Sub Test()
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'also tried set conn = new ADODB.Connection
conString = "xxx"
conn.Open conString
Call routine(conn)
End Sub

Sub routine (conn As ADODB.Connection) 'also tried (conn As Connection)
...
End Sub
```

the error is `ByRef Argument type mismatch` . How can I pass a connection object to a subroutine ?

Comment: Use `set conn = new ADODB.Connection` instead. Also declare it as `Dim conn as ADODB.Connection`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but got `run time error 5 . invalid procedure or argument`

Comment: Show your declaration of `conn`. Make sure you are looking at the **correct** declaration of `conn` by typing SHIFT-F2 while an instance of `conn` in method Test is highlighted.  Also try replacing `Call routine(conn)` with `routine conn`, in case the parenthesis are converting your l-value to an r-value.

Comment: Thank you! I had a wrong declaration as you said. Please copy paste your comments to the answer below, so that i can accept it. I am sure this will be helpful for other people. i searched internet but could not find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set conn = new ADODB.Connection` instead.

Also declare it as `Dim conn as ADODB.Connection`

Show your declaration of conn. Make sure you are looking at the correct declaration of conn by typing SHIFT-F2 while an instance of conn in method Test is highlighted.

Also try replacing `Call routine(conn)` with `routine conn`, in case the parenthesis are converting your l-value to an r-value